# How to nest two formulas in Excel or Google sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to nest these two formulas together. The first is a spreadsheet data search while the second is a formula to make a cell "blank" unless data is input into the cell.

```
=iferror(query(TempDataSet!A2:D,"Select D where lower(D) "&A2&" '"&B1&"'"),"Not found!")

=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)), "", A2-B2)
```

Context - Cell `B1` is my search cell and the output is in cell `B2`. Cell `A2` is conditions/ Data Validations cell

Comment: What cell is each formula in at the moment?

Comment: The top formula is currently in cell B2 by itself. The bottom formula is what I would like to add to B2 with what is currently in that cell.

Comment: `Query` is not an excel formula.

Comment: Google sheets is what I am using

Answer (score 0):

=if(isblank(B1),"",iferror(query(TempDataSet!A2:D,"Select D where lower(D) "&A2&" '"&LOWER(B1)&"'"),"Not found!"))